# Why string is a primitive in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

As far as I know objects can be of any size so you never know how big an object going to be. So it was implemented as a reference type. Unlike any primitive type which size you know in advance.That's what [this article](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch04s04.html) says.
But strings... from another article:

> String : A set of “elements” of 16-bit unsigned integer values.
> Because string is not a fixed value, the variable assigned a string
> does not contain the string but the reference to it.

But how is string of a primitive type then?

Comment: It's the way the language is designed. Does it make a lot of sense? No, but it does not matter; there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Which other article has that quote?

Comment: I'm just curious. I want to know how things work under the hood

Comment: My impression is that the author provides a lot of information that works great in C but doesn't really apply to JavaScript. The tiny foot note ("This is an oversimplification and is not intended as a description of an actual JavaScript implementation.") falls a bit short.

Comment: @jarmod https://18choi18.medium.com/memory-size-of-javascript-primitive-types-6c35ae5a0e00

Comment: Generally, if `typeof variable !== "object"`, it's a primitive, so yes, strings are primitives. Unexpected if you come from something like Java, but yeah.

Comment: @code I'm just trying to use logic. We have a maximum size of number or boolean. But the maximum length of string is  ~2^28 symbols (512MB space). So it makes sense to store it as an object

Comment: JavaScript is a high level language, it doesn't make much sense to think in those terms. Those are implementation details that are only relevant in the language used to write the runtime engine (typically C).

Comment: @scripter2021 Strings are implemented in engines using pointers, just like objects, arrays or functions. But that's not what they *represent* in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That book you're reading is weird.

> A primitive type has a fixed size in memory. For example, a number
> occupies eight bytes of memory, and a boolean value can be represented
> with only one bit. The number type is the largest of the primitive
> types. If each JavaScript variable reserves eight bytes of memory, the
> variable can directly hold any primitive value.
>
> Reference types are another matter, however. Objects, for example, can
> be of any length -- they do not have a fixed size. The same is true of
> arrays: an array can have any number of elements. Similarly, a
> function can contain any amount of JavaScript code. Since these types
> do not have a fixed size, their values cannot be stored directly in
> the eight bytes of memory associated with each variable. Instead, the
> variable stores a reference to the value. Typically, this reference is
> some form of pointer or memory address. It is not the data value
> itself, but it tells the variable where to look to find the value.

And then the author goes on to explain how this causes different behaviour, as if that was an effect of the memory layout. But they've got that the wrong way round. The distinction should be:

- a primitive type has plain, immutable values, that will be copied by value when being passed around.
- a reference type - synonymous with "the object type" - has mutable objects as values, which have an identity (created when the object is instantiated) and can have arbitrary changeable properties. A variable never holds "an object" itself, but rather a reference to it, and it is this reference that is getting copied when you pass it around.

That (and "arrays and functions are objects") is the gist of the JavaScript value model. How this is implemented doesn't really matter - in fact it differs from engine to engine.

Now when you ask "*Why string is a primitive?*", the answer is "because strings are immutable values and don't have properties".

Comment: another question. We have primitive type that stores value like this:
variable => address of a memory cell -> primitive value.
And reference type that works like this:
variable => address of a memory cell -> pointer -> memory cell -> object.

Is that right?

Comment: Different primitive types will have different representations in memory. Small integers, booleans, null and undefined might be stored in the 32 bits of the memory cell. Floating point values might be stored using a 32-bit pointer to a double value elsewhere in memory. Strings and bigints will certainly be stored as pointers to the memory allocated for their values.

Comment: Also variables are usually not "adresses of a memory cell", they're more likely to be offsets in the respective js stack frame. Both so that the same code can be run on different js stack frames, and so that a js stack frame can be moved around in memory.

Comment: so "default" memory cells are usually limited to 32 bits, right? If a value too big then the default memory cell stores a pointer to a bigger memory cell? So bigInts and floats are in fact also reference types? But behave like primitives? Sorry I misunderstood your explanation

Comment: No, no, this totally depends on the implementation - I wrote "*might*". In Google's V8, they found that using 32-bit memory cells (even on 64-bit architectures) leads to smaller memory usage (but there's other optimisations, e.g. there exist array representations with 64-bit cells). Other JS engines differ from this, there are engines that use 64-bit memory cells for everything. But all these *implementation details* don't matter. Booleans, numbers, strings, bigints: they are primitive types, and behave as specified for JavaScript.

Comment: but after all is that true that "bigInts and floats are in fact also reference types? But behave like primitives"?

Comment: No, bigints and numbers are primitive types, not reference types. That storing them in memory requires pointers on usual computer architectures is an implementation detail. Put otherwise: you cannot have a reference to a primitive value in JS, and you can only have a reference to an object in JS (in contrast to other programming languages). This is what defines the terms "primitive value" and "reference value" in JavaScript. That's why I think explaining them through memory representations, oh, even mentioning memory in the first place, is very misleading.

Comment: Small integers, booleans, null and undefined might be stored in the 32 bits of the memory cell. Floating point values might be stored using a 32-bit pointer to a double value elsewhere in memory. trings and bigints will certainly be stored as pointers to the memory allocated for their values. <- doesn't a pointer work like a reference for objects in this case?

Comment: A pointer is a pointer, the only possible difference would how garbage collection is implemented in the engine. But it doesn't matter, a bigint in JavaScript does not work like an object in JavaScript, regardless what tools were used to implement them in a particular engine.

Comment: sorry, it was hard for me to distinguish a pointer from a reference since I'm new to programming and JS is the first language I learn. So the summary:
1) Objects are reference type because they have properties. And not because we never know object's size in advance.
2) Ints and booleans are stored in 32/64-bit memory cells. Strings and bigInts are stored in another type of memory cells. And both booleans and strings use the same type of pointers to point at their memory cell address, only types of cells are different
3) Strings don't have a fixed size but are stored as fixed size types

Comment: Oh I thought you came from C/C++ or something and want to concern yourself with the low-level details. But really you shouldn't, when programming JavaScript. Just think of a "memory cell" (like an object property, array element or a variable) being able to hold either a boolean, number, string, bigint etc. or a reference to an object. It's all the same kind of memory cell, and it can hold any kind of value.